# Expect script sending command prematurely

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

I have an expect script that logs into several computers through `ssh` and starts programs. It has been working fine for a while from but now suddenly a problem has appeared.

It happens at the same time every run; after logging out of a certain computer it attempts to log into the next one before the prompt is ready. That is, the lines

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set multiPrompt {[#>$] }

(...)

expect -re $multiPrompt
send "exit\r"
expect -re $multiPrompt
spawn ssh name@computer4.place.com
```

which should (and normally does) give the result

```
name@computer3:~$ exit
logout
Connection to computer3.place.com closed.
name@computer1:~$ ssh name@computer4.place.com
```

instead gives

```
name@computer3:~$ exit
logout
ssh name@computer4.place.com
Connection to computer3.thphys.nuim.ie closed.
name@computer1:~$
```

and then it goes bananas. In other words the `ssh ...` doesn't wait for the prompt to appear.

Comment: I would add a regex anchor: `set multiPrompt {[#>$] $}`. Is there a timeout issue where it's taking many seconds to close the connection?

Comment: @glennjackman That seems to have solved it, thanks a lot! (If you make it an answer I'll accept it)